# Providing header dependency in meson

Tags: idl, meson-build

I am using meson build system `0.49.0` on `ubuntu 18.04`. My project has some idl files and i want to include header files from another folder. How do I add provide `include_directories` in meson.

```
idl_compiler  = find_program('widl')

idl_generator = generator(idl_compiler,
  output       : [ '@BASENAME@.h' ],
  arguments    : [ '-h', '-o', '@OUTPUT@', '@INPUT@' ])

idl_files = [ .... ]
header_files = idl_generator.process(idl_files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add include directories directly to **generator()** arguments:

```
idl_generator = generator(idl_compiler,
  output       : '@BASENAME@.h',
  arguments    : [ 
        '-h',
        '-o', '@OUTPUT@', 
        '-I', '@0@/src/'.format(meson.current_source_dir()),
        '@INPUT@' ])
```

I added **-I** option which according to [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/widl) can be used to

> Add a header search directory to path. Multiple search directories are
> allowed.

and used meson's [string formatting](https://mesonbuild.com/Syntax.html#string-formatting) together with [**meson**'s object method current_source_dir()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#meson-object) which

> returns a string to the current source directory.

Note also that **output** argument is string, not list.

Or, for example, if you have several of them and need to use them as dependency later, you can have array:

```
my_inc_dirs = ['.', 'include/xxx', 'include']
```

generate args for generator:

```
idl_gen_args = [ '-h', '-o', '@OUTPUT@', '@INPUT@' ]
foreach dir : my_inc_dirs
   idl_gen_args += ['-I', '@0@/@1@'.format(meson.current_source_dir(), dir)]
endforeach

idl_generator = generator(idl_compiler,
  output       : '@BASENAME@.h',
  arguments    : idl_gen_args)
```

and use later for dependency:

```
my_exe = executable(
    ...
    include_directories : [my_inc_dirs],
    ...)
```

Comment: Thank you.! Do you mind sharing the sources? I had a hard time to find this :/

Comment: @debonair no I don't mind, you mean you'd like to share your sources? :)

Comment: or you mean meson sources? Anyway I hope the above is at least close to working because I haven't tested, just gave an idea :)

Comment: I mean where did you find this: `'-I', '@0@/@1@'.format(meson.current_source_dir()` and yes, it is working.